# How to send confirmation messages between clients - PeerJS

Tags: meteor, webrtc, peerjs

I am using [PeerJS](https://github.com/peers/peerjs) to make audio calls between clients and it works. I am showing a Dialog to the user who is receiving a call with two buttons (Answer, and Decline). As shown below:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
  peer.on('call', function(call) {
   // sweetAlert("BINGO")

   bootbox.dialog({
     className: "modal-danger nonumpad",
     closeButton: false,
     animate: true,
     title: 'Call Recieved',
     message: "Accept or Decline",
     onEscape: null,
     buttons: {
      pickup: {
       label: "<i class=\"fa fa-phone\"></i> Answer",
       className: "btn-warning btn-lg pull-left",
       callback: function(){
       return false
      }      
    },
    hangup: {
      label: "<i class=\"fa fa-phone\"></i> Decline",
      className: "btn-warning btn-lg pull-left",
      callback: function(){
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
});





});
```

My question here is, how can I send the action to the other user (who is making the call)?

The reason is because I want to show timer once the receiver press on "Answer" or show dialog to inform the caller that the receiver has pressed decline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PeerJS documentation](http://peerjs.com/):

> ### Data connections
>
> #### Connect
>
> ```
> var conn = peer.connect('another-peers-id');
> conn.on('open', function(){
>   conn.send('hi!');
> });
> ```
>
> #### Receive
>
> ```
> peer.on('connection', function(conn) {
>   conn.on('data', function(data){
>     // Will print 'hi!'
>     console.log(data);
>   });
> });
> ```

You can get the id of the peer making the call via `call.peer` and then open a data connection to send a message (`'accept'`, `'decline'`, etc) to the caller